# Function subset in Xamarin PCL

Tags: .net, xamarin

I am trying to understand the PCL project in Xamarin.

I have figured out and read on the internet that XMLHttpWebRequest GetResponse() is not available under PCL. So far I understand this is because PCL provides only the subset of the targeted platforms. My question is: Which platform does not support this function?

When targeting .NET Framework 4.5, Android, iOS and Silverlight 5, this function doesn't exist. Because the project properties window says that these frameworks all support the same API (.NET 4.5) I assume that there shouldn't be any restrictions. What don't I understand here?

Further, when I create a Xamarin Shared Project and use GetResponse(), it compiles for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) package to your PCL via NuGet. This will allow you to use `GetResponseAsync` in your PCL code that targets Xamarin.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like to know though why this function is not part of the PCL. My investigation showed that it is supported by the target frameworks. Why isn't it there? I am trying to understand the PCL.